# Прогрессбар подгрузки элементов на странице

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Отправляется запрос на загрузку и через echo возвращается ответ в виде html. Если его размер составляет 1.5 Кб, прогрессбар работает. При размере в 75 Кб **lengthComputable** возвращает **false**.

Почему размер загружаемого ответа не определяется или что я делаю не так?

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',

    xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function(e) {
            /* set progressbar value */
            console.log(e.loaded);
            console.log(e.lengthComputable);
        }
    },

    type: 'POST',
    data: {'page': id},
    success: function(data) {
        content.append(data);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['page'])) {

    // Извлечение данных из базы и формирование блока с элементами

    echo '<div class="item">...</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ

```
ob_start();
echo 'data';
$length = ob_get_length();
header('Content-Length: '.$length."\r\n");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'."\r\n");
ob_end_flush();
```

Для получения размера содержимого от сервера (**lengthComputable**), нужно лишь прописать в header'е длину контента. В моём случае я использовал длину символов в переменной загружаемого ответа от сервера

```
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($html));
```

Comment: кастыльже чистой воды вам вообще ненуужен ввод  так удалите ево оставив хеадер

Comment: @naumov, где же тут костыль? Есть начало, через цикл формирования итема из базы присваивается длина хидера в переменную, после цикла устанавливается хидер и отправляются данные, после чего отчистка буфера

Comment: Так вы буфер никак не используете тут и кастыль

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо, если бы не сказал что костыль, не стал бы проверять и не нашёл косяк